# SyncAdapter and Rest Server with paginated response

Tags: android, rest, android-syncadapter

I need to know how to deal with a syncadapter and paginated response from Rest Server. I'm making one android app that retrieves data collection. Each page comes with 20 items and  I'm retrieving all my items in one request now. I think that the best way that I can do it is retrieve one page and when, for example, scrolling to the end of the list view making another request with the syncAdapter but I not sure.

I was searching how to deal in android with pagination in REST but I didn't find anything useful. I wanna know if someone can help me.

Thank you.

Here is an example that how I'm retrieving item now.

```
public ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> parse(String json) throws IOException, NullPointerException {

    final ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> batch = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

    AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(mContext);
    Account account = ((KipptApplication)mContext.getApplicationContext()).getCurrentAccount();
    String authToken = manager.peekAuthToken(account, AuthenticatorActivity.PARAM_AUTHTOKEN_TYPE);

    Header[] headers = new Header[]{
            new BasicHeader(KipptConstants.API_USERNAME_KEY,account.name),
            new BasicHeader(KipptConstants.API_TOKEN_KEY,authToken)
    };


    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type responseType = new TypeToken<Response<ClipObject>>() {}.getType();
    Response<ClipObject> inbox = gson.fromJson(json,responseType);

    List<ClipObject> clips = inbox.getObjects();

    String response = null;
    String next = inbox.getMeta().getNext();

    while(next !=null){

        try {
            Log.d(TAG,"Fetching more clips from: " + next);
            response = HttpHelper.getHttpResponseAsString(KipptConstants.DOMAIN_URL +
                    next, null, headers);
            inbox = gson.fromJson(response,responseType);
            /*Updating next uri*/
            next = inbox.getMeta().getNext();
            if(!inbox.getObjects().isEmpty()){
                clips.addAll(inbox.getObjects());
            }else{
                Log.d(TAG,"No more clips");
                break;
            }
        } catch (PersonalizedException e) {
            Log.e(TAG,e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    for(ClipObject clip : clips){
        if(mKipptDAO.isClipInDb(mContext.getContentResolver(),clip.getId(),true)== null){
            Log.i(TAG,"Adding new clip");
            /*Parsing clip*/
            parseClip(clip,batch,false /*Clip isn't in database so update=false*/);
            /*Parsing media*/
            parseMedia(clip.getMedia(),clip.getId(),batch,false);
            /*Parsing comments if clip contains it*/
            if(clip.getCommentObjects().getCount()>0) {
                List<CommentObject> comments = clip.getCommentObjects().getListElements();
                for(CommentObject comment: comments){
                    parseComments(comment,clip.getId(),batch,false);
                }
            }
            /*TODO Parse Likes*/

            /*Parsing user creator*/
            parseCreator(clip.getUserCreator(),batch,false);

        }else{
            Log.i(TAG,"Modifying clip");
            /*Clip is in database*/
            if(!(clip.getUpdated()<= timestamp)){
                /*Parsing clip and update it in database*/
                parseClip(clip,batch,true);
                /*Parsing media and update it in database*/
                parseMedia(clip.getMedia(),clip.getId(),batch,true);
                /*Parsing comments and update it in database*/
                if(clip.getCommentObjects().getCount()>0) {
                    List<CommentObject> comments = clip.getCommentObjects().getListElements();
                    for(CommentObject comment: comments){
                        parseComments(comment,clip.getId(),batch,true);
                    }
                }
                /*TODO parse likes*/

                /*Parse Creator*/
                parseCreator(clip.getUserCreator(),batch,true);
            }
        }
        /*Updating timestamp*/
        if(timestamp<=clip.getUpdated())timestamp = clip.getUpdated();

    }

    /*Saving timestamp modified value in preferences file*/
    this.sharedPreferences.edit().putLong(KipptConstants.loadTimeStamp(currentFragmentIndex), timestamp).commit();

    return batch;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for using SyncAdapter suggested you try [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQFjABahUKEwiRxNKAqdjIAhVFCiwKHY-GBuM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Ftraining%2Fsync-adapters%2Findex.html&usg=AFQjCNHijN2EUzHgLoxQvRdKWH89tw-e7Q&sig2=3wY85PS5RxBOHIKYO9QWvw).

also for detect end of list in RecyclerView using this:

```
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

                // When went to the end of the list, load more posts
                if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {

                    if (linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition() >= linearLayoutManager.getItemCount() - 1) {

                      // Grow List
                    }
                }
}
```

Comment: i don't think its a good option to use syncadapter for paginated response. Also you have posted about syncadapter and scroll listener separately which is not a concrete example or lead